# WCF Data Services and Entity Framework code first

Tags: wcf, frameworks, entity, wcf-data-services

I found an issue working with WCF Data Services and Entity Framework code first.

I have a class User and ServiceProvider. Class User is an ancestor of the ServiceProvider:

```
[DataServiceKey("Id")]
public class User
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string Name { get; set; }
}  

[DataServiceKey("Id")]
public class ServiceProvider : User
{
    public string AdditionalInfo { get; set; }

    public string ServiceDescription { get; set; }
}
```

When I'm trying to run wcf data service I'm getting an error:

> The server encountered an error processing the request. The exception
>   message is 'Property 'Users' and 'ServiceProviders' are IQueryable of
>   types 'SocialNetwork.Domain.Entities.User' and
>   'SocialNetwork.Domain.Entities.ServiceProvider' and type
>   'SocialNetwork.Domain.Entities.User' is an ancestor for type
>   'SocialNetwork.Domain.Entities.ServiceProvider'. Please make sure that
>   there is only one IQueryable property for each type hierarchy.'. See
>   server logs for more details. The exception stack trace is: ...

I found Paul Mehner's blog which describes this problem but I haven't found the solution.

A link to the blog: http://www.wintellect.com/CS/blogs/pmehner/archive/2010/02/10/windows-communication-foundation-data-services-astoria-the-stuff-they-should-have-told-you-before-you-started.aspx

Do you have any ideas how to fix this issue?
Thank you!

Comment: Did you ever find a resolution to this?

Comment: Nope, this seemed to be a bug of EF